# TextInputLayout not showing when View added programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I noticed some strange behaviour of [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html):

When I add the following to my layout:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
            style="@style/EditTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="In layout"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

everything works as expected.

When I inflate a similar Layout like:

```
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.edittext_w_surrounding_textinputlayout, null);
    EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setHint("Added programmatically");

    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);
    root.addView(v);
```

the `TextInputLayout` doesn't appear and the `EditText` behaves the standard way.

Any ideas what the reason could be?

[image]

Comment: where is layout for root?

Comment: It's in the Activity's layout. It's a LinearLayout to be precise.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should change hint, not on EditText, but on TextInputLayout. So it will be:

```
TextInputLayout v = (TextInputLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.edittext_w_surrounding_textinputlayout, null);
v.setHint("Added programmatically");
```

TextInputLayout has it's own hint parameter and when inflating from layout it get's hint from it's child EditText and set empty hint on it. 
When you want to change hint programatically you have to call textInputLayout.setHint(String text) instead of changing EditText hint

Answer (score 1):

I use this ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framePreview)).addView(preview); with no issues at all, maybe its the view type?
should this

```
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);
root.addView(v);
```

not be this

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
root.addView(v);
```

Comment: I tried different ViewGroup types for 'root' and also assigning them explicitly like you did, made no difference.

Comment: is it because you are adding v and you should be adding editText, editText is where you changed the text

Comment: If a would add only the EditText, the TextInputLayout would be lost.