# Add TextInputLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

How do i go about adding a TextInputLayout programmatically ?

I have tried doing,

```
    private EditText _editText;
    private TextInputLayout _textInputLayout;

    // Create the EditText
    if (_editText == null) {
        _editText = new EditText(this.getContext());
        _editText.setInputType(
                _isPassword ? InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD : InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT
        );
        _editText.setLayoutParams(
                new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        );

        if (_hint != null) {
            _editText.setHint(String.format("%s%s", HINT_PREFIX, _hint.toLowerCase()));
        }

        _textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this.getContext());
        _textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(
                new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, EDIT_TEXT_WEIGHT)
        );
        _textInputLayout.addView(_editText);

        this.addView(_textInputLayout);
    }
```

However, when i compile and run i get the following error. What am i doing wrong here ?

```
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=54; index=108
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getValueAt(TypedArray.java:1132)
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:446)
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextAppearance(CollapsingTextHelper.java:191)
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(TextInputLayout.java:270)
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:111)
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:82)
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:78)
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.syncopatesystems.splogle.iconfloatedittext.IconFloatEditText.initialize(IconFloatEditText.java:145)
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.nixgadgets.iconfloatedittext.IconFloatEditText.<init>(IconFloatEditText.java:75)
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.nixgadgets.iconfloatedittext.IconFloatEditText.<init>(IconFloatEditText.java:62)
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.syncopatesystems.splogle.activities.SignUpWithEmailActivity.onCreate(SignUpWithEmailActivity.java:43) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
10-03 21:22:16.154 2488-2488/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Check this---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294230/textinputlayout-not-showing-when-view-added-programmatically       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544089/textinputlayout-overlap-issue-when-the-text-is-set-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [MaterialEditText](http://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText) libraries. This has way more features than most of the other libraries I have come across.

Answer (score 12):

```
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textInputLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(textInputLayoutParams);
    textInputLayout.addView(editText, editTextParams);
    textInputLayout.setHint("hint");

    setContentView(textInputLayout);
```

Comment: This produces a broken-looking text box with insufficient height. (Using XML works perfectly for me.)

Comment: its a pro-grammatic solution if you want to create programmatic create text input layout

Comment: I'm using this now: `val textInputHolder = TextInputLayout.inflate(this, R.layout.text_input_layout, lin) as LinearLayout` with a bare-bones XML file that just has a TextInputLayout

Comment: @xjcl do you have a sample project or can you elaborate on your solution?

Comment: Just define a simple TextInputLayout with an inner TextInputEditText in an XML file, Android Studio should autocomplete most of this for you anyway. However, I am not using this solution anymore (I'm using XML exclusively) now as I do not need programmatic generation anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class TextClass extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // RealtiveLayout
        // First you create an RelativeLayout which will hold the
        // TextInputLayout
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        // Set generated ID
        relativeLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());
        // Define RelativeLayout layoutParams
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        // Set the layoutParams to the relativeLayout
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);

        // EditText
        // Instantiate EditText view which will be held inside of
        // TextInputLayout
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        // Add an ID to it
        editText.setId(View.generateViewId());
        // Get the Hint text for EditText field which will be presented to the
        // user in the TextInputLayout
        editText.setHint(field.getHint());
        // Set color of the hint text inside the EditText field
        editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        // Set the font size of the text that the user will enter
        editText.setTextSize(16);
        // Set the color of the text inside the EditText field
        editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        // Define layout params for the EditTExt field
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        // Set editText layout parameters to the editText field
        editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);

        /*
         * Next, you do the same thing for the TextInputLayout (instantiate,
         * generate and set ID, set layoutParams, set layoutParamt for
         * TextInputLayout
         */

        // TextInputLayout
        TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);
        textInputLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textInputLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(textInputLayoutParams);

        // Then you add editText into a textInputLayout
        textInputLayout.addView(editText, editTextParams);

        // Lastly, you add the textInputLayout into (or onto) the layout you've
        // chosen.
        relativeLayout.addView(textInputLayout, textInputLayoutParams);
        setContentView(relativeLayout);
    }

}
```

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer to help the user understand

Comment: Sorry for not adding an explanation. First post here. Now the comments are in the code.

Comment: Thank you this helped me when I was rotating my device, the last InputEditText text would be populated across all other ones in the list. Adding the Id to the edit text sorted this issue out

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams  ?