# Dynamically added TextInputLayout is not shown in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-view

I am adding a View in a LinearLayout, this way:

```
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
TextInputLayout til=new TextInputLayout(MainActivity.this);
til.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
Log.i("TAG","BEFORE: "+ll.getChildCount());
ll.addView(til);
Log.i("TAG","AFTER: "+ll.getChildCount());
```

This way, the til object is not shown, but it IS added, because in the second log I see the number has incremented by one, the view I just added.

Why can't I see it? how to show the new view in the layout?

Thank you.

Comment: I think it won't show because your `TextInputLayout` is empty. try to add `TextInputEditText` inside your `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: Try inflating it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294230/textinputlayout-not-showing-when-view-added-programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are forgetting is to add an EditText or a TextInputEditText to the TextInputLayout.

The android documentation says:

> [TextInputLayout is a] Layout which wraps an EditText (or descendant) to show a floating label when the hint is hidden due to the user inputting text.

```java
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);

    editText.setTextSize(16);
    editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    editText.setHint("hint");
    editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));

    textInputLayout.addView(editText, editTextParams);
```

Comment: That was the mistake. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`TextInputLayout` is nothing without having `EditText` as child.

Create a layout file `text_input_layout.xml` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Now, to add, simply inflate this layout and `addView()` to `LinearLayout` as below:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) LayoutInflator.from(this).inflate(R.layout.text_input_layout, null);
linearLayout.addView(textInputLayout);
```

Hope this helps...

**Note:** You can also have `TextInputEditText` as Child of `TextInputLayout`

Comment: how we can fetch user enter data from edit text ?

Answer (score 0):

The `til` has zero height. Use this instead:

`til.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`

Comment: That way is the way it was before I did some changes, and din't work.